# WrapPanel not wrapping content

Tags: wpf, layout, wrappanel

I have the following xaml code in a user control.

```
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="scEmails">
                <ItemsControl Focusable="False" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource UserDataTemplate}">
                    <ItemsControl.Items>
                        <system:String>123</system:String>
                        <system:String>123</system:String>
                        <system:String>123</system:String>
                        <system:String>123</system:String>
                        <system:String>12eee3</system:String>
                        <system:String>123eee</system:String>
                        <system:String>123fefef</system:String>
                    </ItemsControl.Items>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" PreviewKeyDown="txtAuto_PreviewKeyDown" MinWidth="50" />
        </Grid>
```

Here I have a set of items to be shown in the left of a text box. The rendering requirement is:

1. If there are no or little items, let the items occupy as many as space they needed.
2. If there are too many, the items should wrap to next line and expand the `Height` of the control, to ensure the text box get 50 or more pixels width, unless this is impossible (i.e. there is a single item that will use too much space)
3. If there are too many lines (i.e. exceed the limit set by `MaxHeight` property), show the vertical scroll bar.
4. In any cases, the text box shall be given all the space left (in the right hand side!).

I use a `ScrollViewer` to fulfill #3, and use a `WrapPanel` to fulfill #2. But the code above does not give the desired result. In design mode it looks like (the item template is a `TextBlock` inside a `Border`, should'nt matter here)
[image: design mode]

It is not fulfill the requirement because it is not wrapping.

What can I do to fix?

**Update**

If I apply the code in the answer by Raviraj Palvankar and removed all items, the layout in design mode is the following

[image]

However, the desired output (according to requirement term #4) is

[image]

Where my original code does properly (although fails other requirements)

Comment: The column in which ItemsControl lies has auto as it's width, provide MaxWidth or Width to the first Column of your Grid and then it should work.

Comment: Right. But as this is a user control, the MaxWidth or Width should be controlled by its container, not hard coded. Any idea?

Comment: Then change the first column to "*" and the other to "Auto" for a WrapPanel to work, you have to define a fixed width at least inside the container otherwise where will it wrap from?

Comment: As I specified in the question, the text box have minimum width 50 (pixels), and this specifies when to wrap the text. I have tried to swapping them like you said, however the outcome does not meed the requirement - the text box will no longer acquiring all available spaces any more.

Comment: Yes but the TextBox is not a part of the ItemsControl and you want the Items inside the ItemsControl to wrap which means you will have to fix the width of the Items inside the control and not the controls outside because you want the items to wrap.

Comment: No... the width of the items are variable. It can be a single letter or 100 leters...

Comment: Please try doing this once - change <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code without the ItemTemplate and hence looking like that. I added more strings to show that it does wrap.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="50"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="scEmails">
            <ItemsControl Focusable="False" >
                <ItemsControl.Items>
                    <system:String>123</system:String>
                    <system:String>123</system:String>
                    <system:String>123</system:String>
                    <system:String>123</system:String>
                    <system:String>12eee3</system:String>
                    <system:String>123eee</system:String>
                    <system:String>123fefef</system:String>
                    <system:String>123</system:String>
                    <system:String>123</system:String>
                    <system:String>123</system:String>
                    <system:String>123</system:String>
                    <system:String>12eee3</system:String>
                    <system:String>123eee</system:String>
                    <system:String>123fefef</system:String>
                </ItemsControl.Items>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" PreviewKeyDown="txtAuto_PreviewKeyDown" MinWidth="50" />
```

[image: Here is how it looks]

Comment: This way, just fix the width of your first column of the grid so that your items wrap and modify other widths accordingly to suit your requirement.

Comment: This does not fulfill the requirements. See my update.

Comment: I now understood the question. Trying to come up with something, will post as soon as I do. Good question :)